$\cos x-\cos 2x$ stable algorithm
Let $z=\cos x-\cos 2x$.
I have to provide a stable algorithm to compute this in the case when $|x|\ll1$ and prove that the condition numbers
$K_i=\frac{y_i}{z}D_iR_i$ become small.
My problem now is that in any case you have to divide by $z$ which in the case of $|x|\ll1$ goes to zero and the expression becomes large.
How would I best go on about creating an algorithm to compute a difference of two numbers?

Does it help to use the double angle identity to factor the expression?
$$
\cos x - \cos 2x = \cos x - 2\cos^2 x + 1 = (1 - \cos x)(1 + 2\cos x)
$$

@SammyBlack Thanks for the Help! I just computed everything with this algorithm and get condition numbers of $K_1=\frac{1}{3}$ and $K_2=1$. Was trying to make the difference problem a multiplication problem but couldn't see that last transformation.
